# the new data from a later time to replace the current one in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(function(){
         $.ajax({ url: "getLiveData.php",
             success: function(result){
                 $.each(result, function(i, result){
                    var t = $("table#insideTable");
                    t.append('<tr><td>' + result.carNo + '</td><td>' +
                             result.carSpeed + '</td></tr>');
                    });
             }, 
             dataType: "json"
          });
      }, 600000);
});
```

Hello, I was trying to use the code above to update car speeds for every 10 mins.

**--data at 10:20AM-----**

```
+-------+-------+
|car    |speed  |
+-------+-------+
|1      |170 kph|
+-------+-------+
|2      |150 kph|
+-------+-------+
|3      |190 kph|
+-------+-------+
```

**--data at 10:30AM-----**

```
+-------+-------+
|car    |speed  |
+-------+-------+
|1      |180 kph|
+-------+-------+
|2      |155 kph|
+-------+-------+
|3      |174 kph|
+-------+-------+
```

However, after running the code, the results obtained from the two time points are all shown, with one after the other (See below).

```
+-------+-------+
|car    |speed  |
+-------+-------+
|1      |170 kph|
+-------+-------+
|2      |150 kph|
+-------+-------+
|3      |190 kph|
+-------+-------+
|1      |180 kph|
+-------+-------+
|2      |155 kph|
+-------+-------+
|3      |174 kph|
+-------+-------+
```

What I really want is to have the new data from a later time to replace the current one.

```
+-------+-------+
|car    |speed  |
+-------+-------+
|1      |180 kph|
+-------+-------+
|2      |155 kph|
+-------+-------+
|3      |174 kph|
+-------+-------+
```

Can anyone help me?

Many thanks!

Comment: you've completely omitted the important part of the code - the callback function!

Comment: how are you adding it to the dom?

Comment: Thanks @ Alnitak for reminding, the call back function has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `.html()` function in place of `.append()`:

Change:

```
success: function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, result){
        var t = $("table#insideTable");
        t.append('<tr><td>' + result.carNo + '</td><td>' + result.carSpeed + '</td></tr>');
    });
}
```

To:

```
success: function(result){

    //create an output variable that will be added to the DOM when we're finished
    var output = '';

    //iterate through the results of the AJAX request
    $.each(result, function(i, result){

        //add a row to the output variable
        output += '<tr><td>' + result.carNo + '</td><td>' + result.carSpeed + '</td></tr>';
    });

    //add the output to the DOM, notice that since we are only adding nodes to the DOM once this creates less CPU overhead than appending each row separately (we also save overhead by not selecting the table element during each iteration of the $.each() loop)
    $("#insideTable").html(output);
}
```

Which will replace the HTML inside the table element rather than append to it. Here is a demonstration of using `.html()` versus `.append()`: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/TKaVF/

Here is the documentation for `.html()`: http://api.jquery.com/html

On a side-note, it doesn't make your selector any faster by adding `table` since you are looking-up an ID (which is quite fast on its own).

```
var t = $("table#insideTable");
```

Would be faster as:

```
var t = $("#insideTable");
```

Comment: but currenty his append is within an each statement - your going to overwrite the whole table each time ? granted his question formatting is all over the place making it difficult to read ! (updated the formatting in the question now ....)

Comment: I noticed that too and edited my code to build the output before adding it to the DOM (which is much better for performance).

Comment: +1 cool ... looks good ... i have had a few issues  in IE when replacing the innerHTML of a <table> before - thats why i re-wrote the <table> element in my answer ....

Answer (score 1):

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/mnRTf/

change to your success method to :

```
$('#tablecontainerdiv').html('<table>');
$.each(result, function(i, result){
    $("#tablecontainerdiv table").append('<tr><td>' + result.carNo + '</td><td>' +
              result.carSpeed + '</td></tr>');
});
$('#tablecontainerdiv').append('</table>');
```

where `tablecontainerdiv` is a div that the table is contained in for example :

```
<div id="tablecontainerdiv">
  <table>
    //your data here
  </table>
</div>
```

The new code will replace the old table with the new data

Answer (score 0):

Just empty the table before you add the new rows:

```
success: function(result){
             var t = $("table#insideTable"); // moved outside the loop
             t.empty();                      // remove contents of the element
             $.each(result, function(i, result){
                t.append('<tr><td>' + result.carNo + '</td><td>' +
                         result.carSpeed + '</td></tr>');
                });
         }
```